# Broadcast doesn't get started

Tags: android, broadcast

This is my first time trying to create an android app. I'm trying to create a service that can count in the background, and I want the service to broadcast the time to a receiver. It seems like the receiver does not receive anything, though, so I'm not sure if my service gets started at all.

Here's the code where I try to start the service and create the receiver:

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("EXAMPLE_BROADCAST");

    clock = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textClock);

    timeReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setClock(intent.getLongExtra("counter", 0));
        }
    };

    registerReceiver(timeReceiver,filter);

    startService(new Intent(this, CounterService.class));
}

public void setClock(long time){
    clock.setText(String.valueOf(time));
}
```

And here's my service class:

```
public class CounterService extends Service {
private Handler handler;
private long initialTime;
private long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
private boolean isActive;
Intent timeBroadcaster = new Intent("EXAMPLE_BROADCAST");

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();

    Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isActive = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isInteractive();
            if(isActive) {
                timeInMilliseconds += 1000;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
            else {
                if(timeInMilliseconds > 5000) {
                    timeInMilliseconds = 0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
            timeBroadcaster.putExtra("counter", timeInMilliseconds);
            sendBroadcast(timeBroadcaster);
        }
    };
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: did you define the service in manifest ?

Comment: did you register your receiver?

Comment: @Smartiz Yes i did! :/

Comment: @maxost Nope. I wasn't sure if I had to do that. Can you explain how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Runnable* doesn't get executed itself, you need to give it to a thread.

```
Runnable counter = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            isActive = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).isInteractive();
            if(isActive) {
                timeInMilliseconds += 1000;
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
            else {
                if(timeInMilliseconds > 5000) {
                    timeInMilliseconds = 0;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
            timeBroadcaster.putExtra("counter", timeInMilliseconds);
            sendBroadcast(timeBroadcaster);
        }
    };

Thread thread = new Thread(counter);
thread.start();
```

Also register your service in the manifest :

```
<!--Register service-->
  <service android:name="yourpackage.CounterService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your receiver.

In your activity's `onStart` method

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("YOUR_ACTION");
registerReceiver(timeReceiver, filter)
```

In your activity's `onStop` method

```
unregisterReceiver(timeReceiver)
```

And before sending broadcast add your action to `Intent`

```
timeBroadcaster.setAction("YOUR_ACTION");
```

Comment: It requires an IntentFilter in addition to the receiver. How should I create that?

Comment: Still no luck. I updated my code. Can you spot any errors?